# Solving a PDE using $x-vt$ as a variable

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, differentiation, mathematics, ferromagnetism

So I was reading this Landau and Lifshitz paper:
https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-036364-6.50008-9

The article can also be found without a paywall by just searching its title, "On the Theory of the Dispersion of Magnetic Permeability in Ferromagnetic Bodies".

At page 19 (page 6 of my pdf), they have to solve a rather complicated PDE regarding the time dependence of components of a spin field $\boldsymbol{s}(x,y,z,t)$, which is propagating through a material along the $x$ direction, so they have to reduce it to a certain form and make approximations. But I don't entirely understand what they are doing at some point. They assume the variables show up inside $\boldsymbol{s}$ in combinations of the form $x-vt$, and then they write:

$$ \dot{s}_x = -s v'. $$

Below that, it says

> "the prime now denotes differentiation with respect to $x-vt$".

I'm not at all sure how they got this formula. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question on this site should be self-contained. Your link is behind a pay-wall. Edit your question giving all relevant information.

Comment: Which page? Which eq?

Comment: You can actualy find it paywall-free, by searching for its title. I added the relevant information, sorry for forgetting to include it.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption is that spin field propagates in the $x$ direction *at constant speed* $v$, so that if we know $s(x,y,z,t)$ for some given values of $x,y,z,t$ then we can say that at some time interval $\Delta t$ later the field has translated a distance $v\Delta t$ in the $x$ direction, so

$s(x + v\Delta t,y,z,t+\Delta t) = s(x, y, z, t)$

If we say $x_1=x+v \Delta t$ and $t_1=t+ \Delta t$ then we note that $x_1 - v t_1 = x-vt$. Since this is true for any value of $\Delta t$, we can see that the field $s$ does not depend on $x$ and $t$ independently, but only on the combination $x-vt$. So we can replace $s(x,y,z,t)$ by the simpler expression $s^*(x-vt,y,z)$ where we define

$s^*(x-vt, y, x) \equiv s(x,y,z,t)$

and we know that $s^*$ is well defined because we know $s(x,y,z,t) = s(x_1,y,z,t_1)$ as long as $x-vt = x_1-vt_1$.

Comment: I don't really understand this. I understood the replacement already, but where does the formula about the time derivative I quoted come from? Also, why is $v$ being differentiated if it is assumed constant?

Comment: @andreas I do not understand the right hand side of the equation either (I assume the left hand side is $\frac d {dt}$ of the $x$ component of $s$). Maybe the authors define their notation somewhere in the paper ?

Comment: All it says is that the prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x-vt$. I don't really get how that follows... I

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gandalf61's answer,

$$s' = \frac{\partial s(x_1,y,z,t_1)}{\partial t_1} = \frac{\partial s^*(x_1-vt_1,y,z)}{\partial t_1} = \frac{\partial s^*(x_1-vt_1,y,z)}{\partial (x_1-vt_1)} \frac{\partial (x_1-vt_1)}{\partial t_1} = -vs^{*'}$$

Comment: That's the opposite of what is written in the paper, do you think it is a typo?

Comment: Looks like it. v' would be an acceleration. $v$ is constant, so v' would be $0$.

Comment: Perhaps it means -(sv)'